# Can Live Property Explorer display which rule is affecting a certain property?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

The Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer in Visual Studio 2017 is able to display when certain properties are inherited, and what their current values are.

Is there a way to display what style or template a given property is inherited from? Similar to what Chrome's "Styles" tab in the console where it gives you a line number, rule name and rules that govern a certain element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

styles can be inherited and resolved at runtime from dynamically loaded DLLs.

Even the BasedOn could be resolved dynamically in the same way.

So the Key of the style might be the same, but the style itself completely different.

You could use a program such as Snoop to spy on most stuff in WPF application in runtime, and hopefully that will lead you to the source of the style/template.

https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/